# Can we safely assume $\Psi(x,t) = \psi(x)e^{-i\omega t}$ always in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

In the particle in a box, harmonic oscillator and in Hydrogen Atom, we can safely assume $$\Psi(x,t) = \psi(x)e^{-i\omega t}.$$ So why not make it a postulate to consider the wave function to be always in the form $$\psi(x)e^{-i\omega t}$$ We can still explain all the foundational experiments, so my question is why not make this amendment to the theory so that we can avoid a lot of nightmares and some peace of mind. Why unnecessarily consider so general thing when we can do away with simple things most of the time?

Oh my actual question is where do we run into problems (practical physical situations/experiments) if we consider such a thing? If we run into problem anywhere, I hope to make any other simple changes to fix them but without going back on this one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not general. For both the harmonic oscillation and the hydrogen atom, we have a Hamitlonian $\hat{H} = -\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\nabla^2 + V$ with a time-independent potential, which implied that the eigenvalue equation $\hat{H}\Psi(x,t) = E\Psi(x,t)$ is separable, and we can therefore write it as a product of a time-independent factor and a space-independent factor.

In other words, $\Psi(x,t) = \Psi(x)e^{-i\omega t}$ is something we get for the energy eigenstates with a time-independent Hamiltonian. A general solution is a superposition of multiple energy eigenstates, and is not going to have that form.

Comment: You say time independent Hamiltonian, and at the same time involve multiple Energy eigen states, So my question is What is the total energy that is conserved in such a Schrodinger equation?

Comment: @RajeshD that would be the expectation value of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @DavidZ : Again these are contrived, and not really demanded from Schrodinger's equation or from conservation of energy. As I understand, these multiple eigen energies are embedded into the wavefunction and they are not generated by the potential V(x) or from the Hamiltonian, right?

Comment: What I mean is these are set up and not following directly from  te Schrodinger equation.

Comment: @RajeshD: No. The energy eigenvalues are the spectrum of the Hamiltonian, and so generated by it directly. In particular, $\hat{H}\Psi_n = E_n\Psi_n$. Since the Schrödinger equation is linear, any superposition of the eigenstates is a solution, and the fact that cover *all* solutions follows from hermiticity of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Yup, as Stan says, the Hamiltonian induces a set of stationary states, in exactly the same way as how the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of a square matrix are things which are tied directly to that matrix. The wavefunctions follow directly from the Schrodinger equation for whatever problem is at hand when you solve it.

Comment: @StanLiou : Ah now I see, there are many possible energies for different quantum numbers and liner combination (multiplied by Energy values) of corresponding state functions is also a solution to the SE. So silly of me, but the confusion or misnomer arised from the fact than most of the texts and websites don't actually write down the general soluion which is a linear combination.

Answer (score 13):

Another, as of yet unmentioned, reason is for super-position.

For separation of variables techniques, we find $\Psi(\mathbf{x},t)=\psi(\mathbf{x})f(t)$ to give
$$
\frac{i\hbar}{f(t)}\frac{df}{dt}=E=\left[\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V(\mathbf{x})\right]\psi(\mathbf{x})\tag{1}
$$
The term on the left side gives $f\propto\exp\left[iEt/\hbar\right]$, giving us
$$
\psi\left(\mathbf{x},t\right)=\psi(x)e^{iEt/\hbar}\tag{2}
$$
But this is a *stationary* state, but the particle that Equation (1) describes is *not* stationary. Thus, we have that the *general* solution is a linear super-position of states:
$$
\psi\left(\mathbf{x},t\right)=\sum_ic_i\psi_i(x)e^{iE_it/\hbar}
$$

Which cannot be separated into such a form as Equation (2).

Comment: Yes, even with a time-independent Hamiltonian only the eigenfunction are generally time-independent.

Comment: What is the total energy of such a system, in this case?

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as Stan Liou's. I'm not being critical, +1: it's a good answer, and it is always good to have several explanations of the same thing (different writing styles fit different minds): I just make the comment so that other readers don't get confused and are clear that they are very alike answers.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance: I see this now. I guess I hadn't read the last sentence of his answer.

Comment: @Kyle : You say time independent Hamiltonian, and at the same time involve multiple Energy eigen states, So my question is What is the total energy that is conserved in such a Schrodinger equation?

Comment: @KyleKanos No problems: as I said: leave your answer as it is a good one and definitely could be helpful to someone coming to grips with all this as new material.

Comment: @RajeshD The total energy is not uniquely defined when the system is in a mixed state. A measurement of the energy would change that (and you would get each $E_i$ with probability $|c_i|^2$) but it would also change the state to be the corresponding eigenstate.

Comment: @dmckee: Surely you meant a non-stationary state, or superposition of energy eigenstates. Here we're dealing with pure states, and although they're also mixed state by default, a mixed state could have a uniquely defined energy ($\rho = |E_n\rangle\langle E_n|$, say).

Comment: @dmckee : This is very illuminating, could you please give me any good reference or example?

Comment: @RajeshD: dmckee's statement, if understood as referring to superpositions, follows directly from the Born rule.

Comment: Yes superpositions. Forgive my sloppy language.

Comment: @Stan Liou : and dmckee : Again these are contrived, and not really demanded from Schrodinger's equation or from conservation of energy. As I understand,  these multiple eigen energies are embedded into the wavefunction and they are not generated by the potential $V(x)$ or from the Hamiltonian, right?

Comment: You keep using that word "contrived". What do you think it means? The eigenstates and their spectrum are a consequence of the Hamiltonian. If you have a superposition that means that you don't know the energy of the state. There is no surprise that you don't then know what energy you will get if you measure the energy. This is a tautology.

Comment: @RajeshD: Schrödinger's equation is linear, so any superposition of solutions is a solution. Thus you almost never have just one eigenstate for a *general solution* of the SE. Conservation of energy follows from the time-independence of the Hamiltonian, but is otherwise not going to hold. The connection to probabilities of measurement outcomes are and what happens after measurement it not demanded by SE, but by the Born rule. And as dmckee said, the energy eigenvalues are the spectrum of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @dmckee : agreed. I get it now.

Comment: I've been looking at some other resources on this topic and I was wondering if you could explain why there is no negative in your "f" as other sources say its e^-iE...

Answer (score 10):

Only when $V(\mathbf{x},t) = V(\mathbf{x})$, otherwise the time-dependent Schrödinger equation does not separate into time- and space-like parts.

Any explicit time-dependence in the problem and you cannot.

Comment: This Statement and the answer by Stan Liou, should be embossed on every QM text book with a large font size on the cover sheet. Just so that the students are going to relax and also the fact that we are never going for the time dependent potentials. Everybody starts writing $\Psi(x,t)$, which they are never going to use, just to frighten people!

Comment: @RajeshD: Bad news: time-dependent perturbation theory is pretty standard for undergrad QM. Though even if $\hat{H}$ is time-independent, you'll still be coming across situations where you need a non-stationary state.

Answer (score 4):

In a different vein from the other answers, an example of physical a problem in which the solution is not separable is one considered in Sakurai 2nd Edition, Chapter 2.1, Pgs. 70 and 71 where we have a spin magnetic moment in the presence of a magnetic field whose intensity can change with time I.e. $B(t)\neq B(0)$, or even more problematically when the magnitude and direction of the magnetic field change with time. In both cases the Hamiltonian is time dependent and so the solution is not separable.