# Time-dependent and -independent Schrödinger Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

Why do we need both, the time-dependent and time-independent Schrödinger Equations?

Comment: Probably useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91331

Comment: How do you plan to solve time-dependent problems, or write the wave function of a system which does not have definite energy?

Comment: The time-independent SE is not a different equation. It's a subset of the time-dependent SE, and the time independent solution is part of the total solution.  It's good that we can solve the time independent part separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question implies that the time-dependent and time-independent equations are somehow different things, but while technically true this is misleading. The time-independent form is a simplification we can make when the potential does not change with time, so if we start with the time-dependent equation we get the time-independent form for free.

As for why we use the time-independent equation: speaking as an (ex) chemist we're frequently interested in calculating the energy of molecules that are not changing with time. The time-independence means we can use the time-independent Schrödinger equation and it's quicker and easier to use i.e. less CPU time and memory needed to do the calculation.

Comment: I don't fully agree with this answer. The TISE is a *tool*, and the simplification of the TDSE$\to$TISE step is informationally irreversible. Time-independent potentials *can* have time-dependent solutions; it's just that it's much easier to understand those time-dependent solutions as superpositions of $\psi_n(\mathbf r)e^{-i E_nt/\hbar}$s. In this regard, I really recommend David Tannor's [*Introduction to Quantum Mechanics: A Time-Dependent Perspective*](http://www.uscibooks.com/tannor.htm).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty any specific chapter or section of that book?

Answer (score 4):

We don't actually **need** the time-independent equation, but if the potential is constant through time, you can assume that the wave function is separable, $\Psi(x,t)=\psi(x)\xi(t)$ which will give the usual time-independent equation. This method greatly simplifies analytical solutions.

However, it's always possible to find a numerical solution for a time-independent potential using only the time-dependent eq., although not practical.